# symfony2 undefined index when editing/deleting entity 'team' related to FOS users

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have set up a Symfony2 project, with the Sonata and FOS user bundles installed

I generated a custom user class which extends BaseUser. This is an extract:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class User extends BaseUser {
  ..
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Team", inversedBy="members")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(type="integer", name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   */
  protected $team;

  public function setTeam(\MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Team $team)
  {
     $this->team = $team;
  }

  public function getTeam()
  {
    return $this->team;
  }
```

I also have an entity "Team" that can hold some users. This is an extract:

```
class Team {
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="team")
   */

  protected $members;

  public function setMembers(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $members)
  {
     $this->members = $members;
  }

  public function getMembers()
  {
     return $this->members;
  }
```

I use the Sonata Admin bundle to do basic CRUD.
Creating a team with some users is no problem

```
<?php
class TeamAdmin extends Admin {
  protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
  {
    $formMapper

        ->add('members', 'entity', array(
                'required' => FALSE,
                'class' => 'ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User',
                'property' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Team members',
                'multiple' => TRUE,
            ))
    ;
  }
```

The problem rises when i get into the edit screen of a team, or when deleting.

> Notice: Undefined index: team in /Users/sven/projects/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1575

I read a dozen of threads concerning this error, but they all tell me that I used the right field names and column names in the annotations.
Does this have something todo with extending the BaseUser class?

Any help in this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `$this->members = new ArrayCollection()` in __construct() of Team entity?

Comment: Yes I did. But even if I forgot this, the setMembers function does this initialization